# Why does the order of prerequisites matter in a makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I was just learning how to create makefiles and realized that the order of header and object files in the prerequisites of a rule matters, but I do not understand why.

I've researched and talked to many of my classmates, and there was a lot of speculation going on, but nobody had an answer.

I know that during the preprocessing step in compilation, code from the header and source files gets included in object files, so if I'm passing object files and header file as prereqs, why does it matter?

I'm asking because my Makefile should not compile if the header file is missing.

Here is the code:

```
CC = gcc
SRC = main.c file1.c
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
NAME = my_executable
all: header.h $(OBJ)    
     $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)
```

Comment: If `header.h` doesn’t exist and `main.c` depends on it but `main.o` doesn’t list it as a dependency, yeah, the order matters – but `main.o` should have it as a dependency, not `all`.

Comment: Your claim lacks evidence

Comment: I don't known what do you want known, if your source file .c include header file .h and it is missing it is right that make break compilation; if you want remove header file from requirements you have to remove `header.h` from your makefile as this: all: $(OBJ) $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(NAME) Please edit your question...

Comment: It's a bug in your makefile if the behaviour depends on the order of dependencies. You might not notice this initially because gmake typically considers dependencies in left-right order, but it will become apparent when you run make in parallel later

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I [...] realized that order of
>   header and object files in prerequisites of a rule matters but I do
>   not understand why?

Typical implementations of `make` process each target's dependencies in the order they appear in the Makefile.  When such a `make` builds your example `Makefile`'s "all" target, it checks the `hello.h` dependency before any of the files listed in `$(OBJ)`.  Since there is no rule for building it, `make` will fail if that file does not already exist.  Depending on implementation and configuration, it might or might not nevertheless try to build the prerequisites from `$(OBJ)`.

On the other hand, if the header is listed after the other prerequisites, then a `make` that processes prerequisites in order will attempt to build any object files that are missing or out of date before it checks the header.

> I'm asking because my Makefile should not compile if the header file
>   is missing.

See above.  BUT ALSO do understand that you are then relying on a kludge.  Your `Makefile` is flawed in that it does not express the project's dependencies properly.  The `all` target is synthetic; it does not itself really depend on any header.  I suppose that it's some or all of the `$(OBJ)` files that do.  You should therefore express *those* dependencies instead.  Having not done so, you are in the situation that if the project is built and then the header modified, `make` will not rebuild the object files, though it will relink them.

Supposing that all the object files depend on the header, I would modify the Makefile like so:

```
CC = gcc
SRC = main.c file1.c
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
NAME = my_executable
all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)    
     $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $@

$(OBJ): header.h
```

The last line says that every target named in `$(OBJ)` depends on `header.h`. The `$(NAME)` rule says that the real target `$(NAME)` depends on all the objects.  With that, if `header.h` changes then make will rebuild the object files, but at the same time, if *nothing* changes then make will do nothing, not even relink the main executable.  If the header is missing then no attempt will be made to build any of the object files, nor, therefore, the main executable.